# Android Camera : avoid mirror images using front-camera

Tags: android, camera

I am trying to develop a camera application using front facing camera.My preview is correct with front camera but when i capture image it saved as a mirror image of preview.How to fix mirroring effect without using matrix transformation of bitmap?

I tried code from developer site as follows

```
public static void setCameraDisplayOrientation(android.hardware.Camera camera) {
    android.hardware.Camera.CameraInfo info = new android.hardware.Camera.CameraInfo();
    android.hardware.Camera.getCameraInfo(defaultCameraId, info);
    int rotation = activity.getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay().getRotation();
    int degrees = 0;
    switch (rotation) {
    case Surface.ROTATION_0:
        degrees = 0;
        break;
    case Surface.ROTATION_90:
        degrees = 90;
        break;
    case Surface.ROTATION_180:
        degrees = 180;
        break;
    case Surface.ROTATION_270:
        degrees = 270;
        break;
    }

    int result;
    if (info.facing == Camera.CameraInfo.CAMERA_FACING_FRONT) {
        result = (info.orientation + degrees) % 360;
        result = (360 - result) % 360; // compensate the mirror
    } else { // back-facing
        result = (info.orientation - degrees + 360) % 360;
    }
    camera.setDisplayOrientation(result);
}
```

but it is not working for me. What should I do to solve this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The front facing camera is standard mirrored. Your preview mirrors it automatically back to normal. But when you take an image or video, you get directly a frame/image from the camera. So you have to use a matrix to mirror it back.